# Click on a card and then navigate to card page with details ,in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to make a simple application...I fetch some data from backend( a list with announces) and I make a list with them. So, I want that when I push to a button from that announce I want to go to another component where I can see details about that announce. I put my code:

```
    class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            carData: null,
            checkData: false
        }
    }

    getData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/all-articles')
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (response) => {this.setState({
            carData : response,
            checkData : true
        })});
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getData();
    }

    displayCars = () => {
        return(
            this.state.carData.data.map( (object, index) => (
                <CarCard key={index} name = {object.title} description={object.description} img={object.image} id={object.id}/>
            ) )
        );
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.checkData){
            return(
                <div className="App">
                    <Title/>
                    <div className="cars">
                    {this.displayCars()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }else {
            return(
                <div>Loading..</div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default App;


    class CarCard extends React.Component {


    render() {
        console.log(this.goToCardInfo(this.props.id));
        return(
            <div className="card">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={`http://localhost:8000/images/${this.props.img}`}/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{this.props.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                        {this.props.description}
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button variant="primary">See announce</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CarCard;


    class InfoCard extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return(
            <h2>hello</h2>
        );
    }
}

export default InfoCard;
```

I want to say that from backend I fetch id, title,description, price..I googled it but I didn't understand how can I make it..Thank you

Comment: "I want to go to another component " you mean change url to another page to see the infor car or the same page but the carCard is replaced by InfoCard or open an popup? Which one you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the URL to another Page..I fetch data with announces from an api ,in frontend I have a list of announces, and an announce have a button.When I press that button I want to go to another URL and to see informations for that announce

Comment: I provide my answer below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)
I recommend you learn it. Below is my implementation with router.

App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Cars from "./Cars.js" // Change it to the correct path
import InfoCard from "./InforCard.js"

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       <Router>
          <Switch>
             <Route path="/cars" component={Cars}></Route>
              <Route path="/cars/:id" component={InfoCard} exact></Router>
          <Switch>
       </Router>
   }
}
export default App;
```

Cars.js

```
 class Cars extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            carData: null,
            checkData: false
        }
    }

    getData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/all-articles')
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (response) => {this.setState({
            carData : response,
            checkData : true
        })});
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getData();
    }

    displayCars = () => {
        return(
            this.state.carData.data.map( (object, index) => (
                <CarCard key={index} name = {object.title} description={object.description} img={object.image} id={object.id}/>
            ) )
        );
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.checkData){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Title/>
                    <div className="cars">
                    {this.displayCars()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }else {
            return(
                <div>Loading..</div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Cars;
```

CarCard.js

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

class CarCard extends React.Component {
   render() {
        console.log(this.goToCardInfo(this.props.id));
        return(
            <div className="card">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src = {`http://localhost:8000/images/${this.props.img}`}/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{this.props.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                        {this.props.description}
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button variant="primary" 
                                onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/card/" + this.props.id)}>See announce</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(CarCard);
```

InfoCard.js

```
class InfoCard extends React.Component {

    // you can get the id of the card like this
    const url = window.location.hash;
    const id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    // use that id to query your car
    render() {
        return(
            <h2>hello</h2>
        );
    }
}
export default InfoCard;
```